# Getting Error for Copy Task in Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to copy a file on the remote server to the same filename with ".old" appended - so file.crt will have a copy called file.crt.old.

I have a playbook with the following statements:

```
---
- name: Copy current certificate files to 'old' for the PostgreSQL servers
  hosts: all
  become: true
  become_user: postgres
  tasks:
    - name: Copy file
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        remote_src: yes
        src: /<abs path>/Config/file.crt
        dest: /<abs path>/Config/file/server.crt.old

      register: query1
      args:
        warn: no

    - debug: msg="{{ query1.stdout_lines }}"
```

I execute the playbook with the following command:

```
ansible-playbook pg_ckCerts3.yml --ask-become-pass --limit <server name> > test.txt
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
TASK [Copy file] *****************************************************************************************************
fatal: [server name]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (copy) module: warn Supported parameters include: _original_basename, attributes, backup, checksum, content, delimiter, dest, directory_mode, follow, force, group, local_follow, mode, owner, regexp, remote_src, selevel, serole, setype, seuser, src, unsafe_writes, validate"}
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my playbook?  I've tried it a dozen different ways ... with quotes around the filenames & without, yes or true for remote_src, with copy & with ansible.builtin.copy, remote_src specified first or last.  No matter what, I keep getting the same error.

Once I get it working, I actually want to copy more than one file - both the file.crt & the file.key files & then list out the files to verify, so if anyone can also help with that, it would  also be greatly appreciated.

I normally use the following code to list out files, but I can't seem to do more than one task in a playbook at a time:

```
...
  tasks:
    - name: Get hostname, list current certificate files
      shell: |
        hostname
        echo -e "\nCurrent cert files:"
        ls -l --time-style=long-iso /var/lib/pgsql/*/*/<filename>*

      register: query1
      args:
        warn: no

    - debug: msg="{{ query1.stdout_lines }}"
```

Thanks,
Karin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible is telling you that `warn` is not a supported parameter for the `copy` module.

Please try removing it:

```yaml
---
- name: Copy current certificate files to 'old' for the PostgreSQL servers
  hosts: all
  become: true
  become_user: postgres
  tasks:
    - name: Copy file
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        remote_src: yes
        src: /<abs path>/Config/file.crt
        dest: /<abs path>/Config/file/server.crt.old
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I had to remove the register & debug statements also, but then I was able to copy both files & then added another task to list them out afterward.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it solved your issue! Feel free to upvote the answer if you found it useful~

Comment: I tried to give you an upvote, but I'm too much of a newbie ... my reputation isn't high enough.  Thanks again.